# How to inspect docker image entrypoint?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If an base image has an entrypoint, will it be inherited by the image using it?

And, in case the image using it has not defined one, and running docker inspect shows the entrypoint is:

```
"Entrypoint": [
    "container-entrypoint"
]
```

What is this "container-entrypoint"? Didn't find docs on it, but it seems something generic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If an base image has an entrypoint, will it be inherited by the image using it?

Yes.

> What is this "container-entrypoint"? Didn't find docs on it, but it seems something generic.

The `ENTRYPOINT` directive specifies the name of a command. In this case, that command happens to be `container-entrypoint`, which is presumably (a) contained in the image (b) in a directory that is on `$PATH`.

The `container-entrypoint` command is *probably* a script. Assuming that your image has a shell, the easiest way to inspect it is to replace the entrypoint with a shell and then explore the container filesystem:

```
docker run --entrypoint sh myimage
```

Then examine directories in `$PATH` to find the script. There's a good chance it lives in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: That's sounds like a plan. Thank you. :)

Comment: Quick way to see entrypoint from a given image (in his case nginx:latest) :
docker inspect nginx:latest|jq .[].ContainerConfig.Entrypoint